# Updating & Upgrading

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upgrade from 10.04 or 11.10 to 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04)

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 and I am very interested in upgrading to the new 12.04, but my update manager won't recognize that the new version is out apparently because when I run it.. all it says is that the newest version is 10.10 and that it isn't supported.... I am fairly new to using Linux Ubuntu OS and already I love the freedom I get from it.. I would greatly appreciate it if you at Ubuntu could help me make the most of my experience.. Please help me understand why I can't automatically upgrade to 12.04 or atleast 11.10.

Thank You for your time in reading this,

-Joshua Mason

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> on your keyboard and type in `update-manager -d`

and follow the instructions, or

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then use update manager to check for updates

For complete details on how to upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin from 10.04, 11.04, 11.10, [See this site](http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-1004-1010-1104-to-ubuntu-1110-oneiric-ocelot-desktop-a-server/)